# Is it possible to have exactly once semantics, for one producer with multiple consumer in Reactive Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, project-reactor

I wonder if it's possible to implement exactly-once semantic with distributed consumer, in reactive manner.

In the [reference doc for Reactor Kafka](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/), we have a sample code for Exactly-once delivery. The thing is that the Receiver must have access to the TransactionManager owned by KafkaSender.

Can we have a shared TransactionManager, that will handle all this mess? We do have similar function by using KafkaTransactionManager for regular Spring Kafka. But this is different and cannot be used in Reactor kafka.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Since the transaction manager owns the producer and is used to start the transaction on that producer, you need a different `TransactionManager` (and sender) instance (with a different `transactional.id`) for each receiver.

Comment: The scenario is that I have multiple applications running, and one producer should be able to `sendTransactionally` to a topic, hoping exactly one receiver will process that. I'm not sure if that is architecturally makes sense. It's important that the message only processed exactly once.

Comment: "Exactly Once" means an entire `consume->process->produce` sequence will be performed exactly once but, if the `produce` step fails, the `consume->process` part is at least once. Whether the original record was sent transactionally or not is irrelevant and unrelated to the consumer processing.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. and exactly what I want. But isn't EOS only possible if sent within a transaction? What we want to prevent is that the other Consumer to consume the message, and becomes more-than-once processing.